# How to configure Log4j2 by runtime-path (working directory) XML file, not classpath

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j, log4j2

I cannot [configure Log4j2](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#XML) to **read configuration from XML file in working directory**.

I was trying to set system property as documentation says:

> Log4j will inspect the "log4j.configurationFile" system property and,
>   if set, will attempt to load the configuration using the
>   ConfigurationFactory that matches the file extension

with Main class static initializer block, also in `main` method, with relative and absolute paths:

- `System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY,
  "E:/log4j2.xml");`
- `System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY,
  "./log4j2.xml");`
- `System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY,
  "log4j2.xml");`

Also with `"log4j.configurationFile"` instead of `XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY` and nothing of that works.

This configuration **works only if I add XML to my classpath by putting it in `src` directory**. I want to allow post-compilation lightweid configuration by editing XML file in working directory.

Used dependencies:

- [`log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-core/2.0-beta9)
- [`log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-api/2.0-beta9)
- [`log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-beta9.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j-slf4j-impl/2.0-beta9)
- [`slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar`](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Works fine for me.

```
public class Runtimeconfig {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY, "/home/peter/config/log4j2.xml");
        new LoggedClass().logMe();
    }
}


public class LoggedClass {
    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(LoggedClass.class);

    public void logMe() {
        logger.info("I'm logged!");
    }
}
```

It breaks when you use

```
static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Runtimeconfig.class);
```

in your class where the main method is located, because static fields where initialized first.

What will work also is the following

```
public class Runtimeconfig {

    static {
        System.setProperty(XMLConfigurationFactory.CONFIGURATION_FILE_PROPERTY, "/home/peter/config/log4j2.xml");
    }

    static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(Runtimeconfig.class);

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new LoggedClass().logMe();
        new Runtimeconfig().logger.info("I'm logged too");
    }
}
```

but then you rely on the order of static field initialization execution.

Comment: What a pitty, I know about static priotity, but I usef instance initializer instead of static initializer by mistake :)